# ServiceStack.OrmLite 5.1.1: "host... does not support SSL connections"

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I upgraded to version 5.1.1 of ServiceStack OrmLite (via MyGet), and when I try to open a connection to the db, I suddenly get this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'The host 127.0.0.1 does not support SSL connections.'

Before the upgrade I was running v 5.1.0, and I got no such error.

I initialize OrmLite as follows:

```c#
private void InitOrmLite()
{
    JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
    OrmLiteConfig.ThrowOnError = JsConfig.ThrowOnError = true;
    //OrmLiteConfig.BeforeExecFilter = dbCmd => Console.WriteLine(dbCmd.GetDebugString());
    _dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory($"Uid={dbUsername};Password={dbPassword};Server={dbAddress};Port={dbPort};Database={dbDatabase}", MySqlDialect.Provider);
    SetTableMeta();
}
```

and usage is

```c#
using (var _db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    // AlterTable will create if not exist, otherwise add columns that was added to the PCO 
    _db.AlterTable<Customer>(MySqlDialect.Provider);
}
```

And here it is:

[image]

There is a workaround, that I am posting as an answer, but I'd like mythz input on this =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround that I found, is to add the following to the connection string:

> SslMode=None

so, the connectionstring would be:

> $"Uid={dbUsername};Password={dbPassword};Server={dbAddress};Port={dbPort};Database={dbDatabase};SslMode=None",
>   MySqlDialect.Provider

When doing so, the exception is gone.

Comment: Yeah [ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql](https://www.myget.org/feed/servicestack/package/nuget/ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql) v5.1.1 on MyGet has been upgraded to use the latest MySql.Data v8.0.11 which now requires this.